# Difficulty parsing JSON into HTML, results undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to parse YAHOO data using getJSON and YQL

The connection works well, I retrieve data which I can see and log to console, but I cannot then get the data to print into the JSP page I'm using. I've used the answer accepted here:

http://jsbin.com/umuri5/1/edit

with little success. Here is my JSP:

```
<%@page import="p.build.classes.p.*"%>

<!DOCTYPE JSP>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
<title>untitled</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body { text-align: center; }
</style>
</head>
<body onLoad="gova();">

<div id="container">

</div>
<table id="userdata" border="1">
    <thead>
        <th>Change</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<script id="userTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr>
        <td>${Change}</td>
    </tr>
</script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>   
<script src="https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl/master/jquery.tmpl.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function gova() {
requestCrossDomainJSON(
    'yahoo.finance.quote',
    function(results) {
        var i, t = $('#userTemplate'), tbody = $('#userdata tbody');
      // console.log(data.query.results);

        for (var i = 0; i < results.userdata.length; i++) {
            t.tmpl(results.userdata[i]).appendTo(tbody);
        }
    }
);
return false;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my script, script.js:

```
function requestCrossDomainJSON( site, callback ) {  


  if ( !site ) {  
    alert('No site was passed.');  
    return false;  
  }  


var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20Change%20from%20' + site + '%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22YHOO%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=?';  

// Request that YSQL string, and run a callback function.  
// Pass a defined function to prevent cache-busting.

function cbfunc(data) {
    console.log(data);
      // If we have something to work with...
      if ( ! data.error && data.query.results) {
          // If the user passed a callback, and it
          // is a function, call it, and send through the data var.
          if ( typeof callback === 'function') {
              callback(data.query.results.json);

          }

      }
      // Else, Maybe we requested a site that doesn't exist, and nothing returned.
      else throw new Error('Nothing returned from getJSON.');

  }
  // Request that YQL string, and run a callback function.
  // Pass a defined function to prevent cache-busting.
  $.getJSON( yql, cbfunc );

 //    console.log(data.query.results);


 };
```

The error occurs at the line:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < results.userdata.length; i++) {
            t.tmpl(results.userdata[i]).appendTo(tbody);
        }
```

where the console says it cannot read property userdata of undefined. Because JQuery template is depreciated, should I be using a better method to get this data into my page?If this is still a valid solution to the problem I am having, how should I reference results from the called JSON if it is undefined in the function provided. I've tried using an HTML file in lieu of a JSP as well.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `results` portion of the response from [the URL you're making the request to](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20Change%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22YHOO%22%29&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys) returns:

```
results: {
     quote: {
          Change: "-0.061"
     }
}
```

Are you expecting this?

If so, you'll want to grab `data.query.results['quote']['Change']` or `data.query.results.quote.Change` instead of trying to pass `data.query.results.json` into the callback and then look through `results.userdata`

Comment: Thank you for the help, but when I replace the loop that returns the error with       
 for (var i = 0; i < results.quote.Change.length; i++) {
                t.tmpl(results.quote.Change[i]).appendTo(tbody);
            }  
I get the same error, but with "quote" undefined instead.

Comment: there's no need to loop through anything. simply grab the response: `data.query.results.quote.Change`and pass that into `tmpl`. You'll want to keep in mind that it's worth checking to see if each sub-object exists as you're accessing them, but that'll get you going.

Comment: I'm sorry, there still appears to be something wrong with data.query.results.quote.Change. After removing the loop and simply referring to 
            t.tmpl(data.query.results.quote.Change).appendTo(tbody);
I cannot get access to the data returned, it says, in this case, that data is not supported by tmpl.

Comment: I've also changed the data.query.results.json callback in my script

Comment: wanna create a fiddle? can certainly help debug that

Comment: I would love to create a fiddle, but JSFiddle doesn't like the loop with the temp arguments in it in either the html block or the js block

Comment: you're passing the actual value into the callback function: `callback(data.query.results.quote.Change);` and then you're trying to loop through non-existant results. either (1) stop trying to loop through stuff, so in your callback function, use 'results.quote.Change' instead of the forloop. or (2) pass `data` into the callback and then access the value via `data.query.results.quote.Change`. either way: no for loop is necessary!

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ojaven/3/: sorry I forgot to make any edits in the Bin, this is as far as you have advised me to go, I'm not sure what I can do to fix it because I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: the callback function is getting `results` into the callback, but you're trying to access `data.query.results.quote.Change`. change the `results` argument to `data` and i believe you should be all set. also, you should pass the `quote` object into the context of the template, so instead, use: `data.query.results.quote`

Comment: Brilliant, worked well, I need to work on my XML data references a little bit it seems, this was a good crash example.